# Linking a Jython and Python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, process, jython

I know that Jython doesn't include all of the standard python library, but say if I had a cpython thread organizing everything with c libraries and then a jython thread to control my java based devices could this work out somehow?

Comment: I'm afraid jython and python must run in different processes. Maybe someone has created a hack to run them in one process (for example embedding a python interpreter as a jni module) but even in that case the communication is not simply python-to-python. Once I've read that some cpython libraries have been ported to jython (for performance) but I don't know more about this as I'm not a jython user. BTW, why do you need both cpython and jython?

Comment: if you really need java classes in cpython code you could use `jpype` I use it, but I wish I didn't have to sometimes

Comment: @pasztorpisti I need to address my android phone via monkeyrunner but I also need to use opencv and some other cpython libraries in conjuction.. I didn't think it would really be possible but I thought I'd have the best shot asking here. Could I use addresses in the memory like C perhaps?

Comment: If we take a look at your problem from higher level then the problem is that you have to perform communication, data passing between the jvm and something else. This communication doesn't have to be a function call or something similar on python language level, you could connect the two processes with simple IPC like a pipe or my favorite: loopback socket. Of course in some edge cases you cant afford using this as a solution but if you don't have to pass data quite often (you could batch) and the data isn't too large then it is a very flexible option.

Comment: @pasztorpisti thanks for the idea, but unfortunately I would need a constant stream of information to the jvm as I will be actively analyzing OpenCV data to send to the android device. Any other ideas :) ?

Comment: @Clement And do you think that the latency/overhead of sockets is unacceptable? It gives you a lot of flexibility, its a platform independent solution, you can put any kind of program C/java/perl/python to the endpoints of a socket connection. If you want to put java and cpython into a single process then they have to communicate through jni regardless whether cpython loads the jvm or the jvm loads cpython as a jni binding. And programming jni sucks hard, especially if you have to compile your binding C code to other platforms. Its just dirty work.

Comment: @Clement I've just checked out jpype recommended by Brad, it allows you to start basically a jvm from cpython (probably within the same process) and then you can call into the jvm from cpython (and its api partly reminds me of the ugly jni...). If it isn't a problem that cpython launches your jvm (and not you from commandline or from somewhere else) then this is a viable solution. The jvm runs your java threads and from cpython you could call a java function that waits until there is work for cpython and then it returns the processable data to cpython.